# Specific Object Save in Reducer in React Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm trying to save the reducer `auth` when i login. My problem is not all values in `auth` i want to save when i login, i only want to save `infos` and `token`.

Pls check my code below
**authReducer**

```
const authReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case authConstants.LOGIN_REQUEST:
      return {
        ...state,
        token: null,
        infos: null,
        isLoggedIn: false,
        errors: null,
        isLoading: true,
      };
    case authConstants.LOGIN_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        token: action.payload.token,
        infos: action.payload.user[0],
        isLoggedIn: true,
        errors: null,
        isLoading: false,
      };
    case authConstants.LOGIN_FAILED:
      return {
        ...state,
        token: null,
        infos: null,
        isLoggedIn: false,
        errors: null,
        isLoading: false,
      };
    case authConstants.LOGOUT:
      return {
        ...state,
        token: null,
        infos: null,
        isLoggedIn: false,
        errors: null,
        isLoading: false,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
export default authReducer;
```

**index**

```
import auth from './authReducer';
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import user from './userReducer';

const combinedReducer = combineReducers({
  auth,
  user,
});

const rootReducer = (state, action) => {
  if (action.type === 'Auth/LOGOUT') {
    state = undefined;
  }

  return combinedReducer(state, action);
};

export default rootReducer;
```

**store.js**

```
 // Redux
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import rootReducer from './reducers';

// Redux Dev Tools
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension';

// Redux Persist
import { persistStore, persistReducer } from 'redux-persist';
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage';

const persistConfig = {
  key: 'auth',
  storage: storage,
  whitelist: ['auth.infos', 'auth.token'], // which reducer want to store
};

const pReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer);
const middleware = [thunk];
const store = createStore(pReducer, composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(...middleware)));
const persistor = persistStore(store);
export { persistor, store };
```

Comment: can you please provide more details.

Comment: @Paveloosha. Just added it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create a function that will help to persist/whitelist some part of the state. i.e.

```
import storage from "redux-persist/lib/storage";
import { persistReducer } from "redux-persist";

export default function persist(key, whitelist, reducer) {
  return persistReducer(
    {
      key,
      storage,
      whitelist
    },
    reducer
  );
}
```

After that you can use the function in the **authReducer**.

```
import persist from 'path/to/persist';

const authReducer = (state = initialState, action) => { 
  // other code 
}
 
export default persist('auth', ['infos', 'token'], authReducer);
```

And now you can remove `persistConfig` and `persistReducer` from **store**.

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import rootReducer from './reducers';

// Redux Dev Tools
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension';

// Redux Persist
import { persistStore } from 'redux-persist';

const middleware = [thunk];
const store = createStore(rootReducer, composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(...middleware)));
const persistor = persistStore(store);
export { persistor, store };
```

[Credit](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist/issues/277#issuecomment-478965157)

Comment: It still doesn't save the token and infos :(

Comment: Just added my index reducer. I don't know if could help

Comment: can you add how you used the persist function in authReducer

Comment: Did you rebuild your app ?

Comment: Hi! yes. I just noticed, if i do this, it works `export default persist('auth', ['token'], authReducer);`

Comment: You can save one in this ['token']?

Comment: there is typo in answer `['infos, token']`

Comment: it must be `['infos', 'token']`

Comment: You got it. Thanks a lot

Comment: Yeah got that. Glad to help.